# Is there any way to make the quill better-table uneditable?

Tags: javascript, quill

I have a quill editor with a quill-better-table module. I want it to be uneditable at certain times, so I set it to readOnly. This works for buttons and text, but the table is still editable. The context menu (operationMenu) is also available.

Is there any way to make the better-table uneditable?

```
const quill = new Quill('#editor-wrapper', {
    theme: 'snow',
    readOnly: this.readOnly || false,
    modules: {
      table: false,  // disable table module
      'better-table': {
        operationMenu: {
          items: {
            unmergeCells: {
              text: 'Another unmerge cells name'
            }
          }
        },
        toolbar: {
         container: [
          ['tableCreate'],  // custom button for create table
                        ],
         handlers: {
            'tableCreate': () => this.addCreateTableBtnEvent()
                    }
         },
      }
    }
  })
```

```
addCreateTableBtnEvent: function () {
        const table = quill.getModule('better-table');
        table.insertTable(2, 2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not an elegant solution and **the modification must be taken into account if I upgrade quill-better-table.js** in the future, but so far it works.

I edited the quill-better-table.js and put in checks whether the Quill editor is editable or not.
If it's not editable  than there is no content menu or column tool on the quill-better-table.

You can skip any function of the quill-better-table in this way.

```
...
menuInitial(_ref) 
{
    let {
      table,
      left,
      top
    } = _ref;
    var editable = this.quill.root.getAttribute("contenteditable")
    if ( editable === 'true' )
    {
    
        this.domNode = document.createElement('div');
        this.domNode.classList.add('qlbt-operation-menu');
..
```